# How to add unused space to another partition in gparted?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, operating-systems, gparted

In my hard drive windows takes up 100 gb, then backtrack takes up 100 gb. When I make backtrack's partition smaller i get 100 gb for windows, 50 gb for backtrack, and 50 gb of unused space (in that exact order). How do I reallocate that 50 gb of space to windows so that instead it is 150 gb for windows, then 50 gb for backtrack? I'm using gparted and i can't move the unused space or add it to windows' partition.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how the resizing went and how your partitions are arranged, there are a couple issues i can think off..

- The free space is on the far end of the windows partition - i.e [windows] [Linux] [Free]:-    In this case you might need to move the linux partition to the end and then resize the windows partition to include the free section
- It could also be that the linux partition is a logical partition? :- In that case you would need to resize down the extended partition that encloses it before you can resize the windows.

In either case i would recommend gparted on a live cd/usb setup since you would need to move the linux partition and that isnt possible if that same linux is currently booted.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would just to set it to a NTFS partition and use it as storage, as attempting to add the 2 partitions together could end up formatting both partitions.

Mind you if you go to disk management in windows, I think you possibly will be able to re add it to the partition from there.